# DirectShow throws error on my Source Filter (UNSUPPORTED_STREAM) that i use to decrypted the buffer stream

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

I compiled and registered the DLL that is included in the DirectShow samples ( Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\multimedia\directshow\filters\async) I modified it to decrypt the buffer as I receive it (Because the file I received is encrypted. I can run the example on GraphStudioNext but whenever I try to construct the graph on C# with DirectShowLib it keeps giving me errors.

```
IBaseFilter xAsync = CreateFilter("C553F2C0-1529-11D0-B4D1-00805F6CBBEA");
hr = graphBuilder.AddFilter(xAsync, "xAsync");

hr = this.graphBuilder.RenderFile(filename, null);
```

it returns the -2147220891 (VFW_E_UNSUPPORTED_STREAM) (Cannot play back the file: the format is not supported.) Is there a way to get around this?

EDIT: This issue does not happen if I remove my decryption code.

Comment: Probably you're running 32-bit graph studio and 64-bit C# app. Or the other way.

Comment: For C#, if you are builtding "Any CPU" config, bitness depend on "Prefer 32 bit" in project settings.

Comment: @Soonts - Thank-you for the reply, the two prepossess are graphstudionext.exe *32 and PlayWnd.vshost.exe *32 in my task manager so I believe they are both 32 bit already :(

Comment: Well in this case, use this answer to gather more information why it’s failing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7215285/126995

Comment: P.S. If you’d picked newer technology stack, you’d get a nice GUI tool for that, google “MFTrace”

Comment: This is where you need to debug it. Apparently your decryption does not work as you expect it.

Comment: Thank-you guys, I will debug it, I just found it really weird it would work on GraphStudioNext and not in code :( MFTrace is wonder ty @Soonts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the issue. I had to build the graph from scratch and not reply on RenderFile. I had to manually connect my Custom File Source reader. The reason why it returns -2147220891 (VFW_E_UNSUPPORTED_STREAM) is because I encrypted the entire file included in the header information that the system relies on to determine the rest of the filters to connect to.

My Graph ended up with FileSourceCustom -> GDCL Demultiplexer -> FFDShowDecoder -> VMR9